# VPN tun interface ports are closed

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, port, forwarding

I have an issue with accessing my server of Cryptully chat under vpn. What I did (S - server side, C - client side):

```
S: python cryptully.py -s -p 1242
S: sudo netstat -autpln | grep 1242
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1242            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4978/python
C: sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client.ovpn
C: sudo nmap -sS 10.8.0.1 -p 1242
Nmap scan report for 10.8.0.1
Host is up (0.000068s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1242/tcp closed unknown
```

For example, ports number 80 and 22 are accessible:

```
C: sudo nmap -sS 10.8.0.1 -p 80
Nmap scan report for 10.8.0.1
Host is up (0.000069s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
C: sudo nmap -sS 10.8.0.1 -p 22
Nmap scan report for 10.8.0.1
Host is up (0.000058s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

Also related rules from the server iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:1194
ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
REJECT     all  --  !lo    *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  tun+   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   tun+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 981K packets, 1013M bytes)
ACCEPT     all  --  *      tun+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

And the result of testing another port:

```
S: python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
C: sudo nmap -sS 10.8.0.1 -p 8000
Host is up (0.000059s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8000/tcp closed http-alt
C: sudo nmap -sS 192.168.1.183 -p 8000
Host is up (0.00019s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8000/tcp filtered http-alt
```

Even after `sudo iptables -F` ports on the tun interface are still closed, but on the eth0 are open now.

```
S: python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
C: sudo nmap -sS 10.8.0.1 -p 8000
Host is up (0.000068s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8000/tcp closed http-alt
C: sudo nmap -sS 192.168.1.183 -p 8000
Host is up (0.00021s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8000/tcp open  http-alt
```

What could be the possible reason of that?

Answer (score -1):

Problem has gone after shutdown of openvpn server with the same mask on my client machine. I just did not mention that I have it's executed on my client, sorry guys :) This case some requests goes to the right destinations and some goes wrong. For example, I could easily access to nginx on the 80 port, but could not access others, that is strange... But now problem has gone away and I'm happy :) Happy new year!